# Why do I have two vertical scrollbars after switching from ReactJS to NextJS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scroll, next.js

I built a little project in plain ReactJS and put those two lines in my `index.css` file:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

I put them there so I would never have a horizontal scrollbar and always a vertical scrollbar (even if there is nothing to scroll so the contents would not move)

Now I converted the same project into a NextJS app and have the same two lines in my `globals.css`. The `index.css` does not exist here. But now the result is two vertical scrollbars:

[image]

I made a global search in my project for the two lines, but I only found them in my `globals.css` file.

Why is this so? And how can I get my desired behaviour back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the solution.

After inspecting the scrollbars in chrome, I found out that they were generated on html level. So I put my two lines

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

into the html block instead of the body block and it worked.